# PySpark approxSimilarityJoin() not returning any results

Tags: pyspark, databricks, nearest-neighbor, euclidean-distance

I am trying to find similar users by vectorizing user features and sorting by distance between user vectors in PySpark. I'm running this in Databricks on Runtime 5.5 LTS ML cluster (Scala 2.11, Spark 2.4.3)

Following the code in the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#approximate-similarity-join), I am using `approxSimilarityJoin()`  method from the `pyspark.ml.feature.BucketedRandomProjectionLSH` model.

I have found similar users successfully using `approxSimilarityJoin()`, but every now and then I come across a user of interest that apparently has no users similar to them.

Usually when `approxSimilarityJoin()` doesn't return anything, I assume it's because the `threshold` parameter is set to low. That fixes the issue sometimes, but now I've tried using a `threshold` of 100000 and still getting nothing back.

I define the model as

`brp = BucketedRandomProjectionLSH(inputCol="scaledFeatures", outputCol="hashes", bucketLength=1.0)`

I'm not sure if I changing `bucketLength` or `numHashTables` would help in obtaining results.

The following example shows a pair of users where `approxSimilarityJoin()` returned something (`dataA`, `dataB`) and a pair of users (`dataC`, `dataD`) where it didn't.

```
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.sql.functions import col


dataA = [(0, Vectors.dense([0.7016968702094931,0.2636417660310031,4.155293362824633,4.191398632883099]),)]
dataB = [(1, Vectors.dense([0.3757117100334294,0.2636417660310031,4.1539923630906745,4.190086328785612]),)]

dfA = spark.createDataFrame(dataA, ["customer_id", "scaledFeatures"])
dfB = spark.createDataFrame(dataB, ["customer_id", "scaledFeatures"])

brp = BucketedRandomProjectionLSH(inputCol="scaledFeatures", outputCol="hashes", bucketLength=2.0,
                                  numHashTables=3)
model = brp.fit(dfA)

# returns
# theshold of 100000 is clearly overkill
# A dataframe with dfA and dfB feature vectors and a EuclideanDistance of 0.32599039770730354
model.approxSimilarityJoin(dfA, dfB, 100000, distCol="EuclideanDistance").show()



dataC = [(0, Vectors.dense([1.1600056435954367,78.27652460873155,3.5535837780801396,0.0030949620591871887]),)]
dataD = [(1, Vectors.dense([0.4660731192450482,39.85571715054726,1.0679201943112886,0.012330725745062067]),)]

dfC = spark.createDataFrame(dataC, ["customer_id", "scaledFeatures"])
dfD = spark.createDataFrame(dataD, ["customer_id", "scaledFeatures"])

brp = BucketedRandomProjectionLSH(inputCol="scaledFeatures", outputCol="hashes", bucketLength=2.0,
                                  numHashTables=3)
model = brp.fit(dfC)

# returns empty df
model.approxSimilarityJoin(dfC, dfD, 100000, distCol="EuclideanDistance").show()
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to obtain results to the second half of the example above by increasing the `bucketLength` parameter value to `15`. The threshold could have been lowered because the Euclidean Distance was ~34.

Per the [PySpark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.feature.BucketedRandomProjectionLSH):

`bucketLength = the length of each hash bucket, a larger bucket lowers the false negative rate`